# Using Mapbox GL JS in Vue after initialization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox-gl-js

My `Map.vue` is below, with parts of the code abbreviated so I don't expose any information. The Map is a component of my app and I would like to add some interactions to it. However, my `method` won't work, saying `read property 'getPitch' of undefined`. How can I initialize the map so that Mapbox's functions are still available later on?

```
<template>
    <div id="map" class="map">
        <button @click="getPitch">Test</button>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

export default {
    name: "Map",
    data() {
        return {
        };
    },
    props: {
        mapdata: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => { return {}; }
        }
    },
    beforeUpdate() {
            
        mapboxgl.accessToken = "...";

        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: "map",
            style: "...",
            center: ...,
            zoom: 11.85,
        });

        let mapRecords = this.mapdata.data;

        map.once('styledata', function() {

            map.addSource('...', {
            ...
            });

            map.addLayer({
            ...
            })
        });

    },
    methods: {
        getPitch() {
            map.getPitch();
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
...
</style>
```

**Solved**

First, changed all `map` instances in `beforeUpdate()` to `this.map`. Then, in the `getPitch` function, added this line: `let map = this.map;`.

Comment: I assume this is Vue 3 again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beforeUpdate` does not look like the right hook. You probably should be using `mounted`.

Also, your variable `map` is out of scope for your `getPitch` method.

Comment: `beforeUpdate` still works, since I'm waiting for data from the parent (the `mapdata` object). As for the second part, you were right.

Comment: However, if `mapdata` changes, you will create a whole new instance of `map` which probably isn't what you want.